# jFormatted text field is not formatting the double data correctely

Tags: java

I've a `jFormmatedTextField` which is displaying double data incorrectly.
the field is formatted like this `##,##0.00` , however when the value of this field is set using `setValue` its sometimes displaying something like 77.88899888 which it should not.
this problem is happening for example when when I multiply 20.38 x 20 but when I multiply 20.38 x 15 its displaying correct number.
I dont understand why is this happening.

the code is like this:

```java
resultField.setValue(new Double(myResultField));
```

Comment: Can you give an example with the code?

Comment: Edit your question and show us your code.  It sounds like you created a [NumberFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html);  did you remember to pass that NumberFormatter to the JFormattedTextField constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for arithmetic precision operations, try to use BigDecimal instead of Double field. This takes care of rounding up data to the precision you need. You can see it for yourself with the below code :

```
    Double a = 20.38
    Double b = 20
    println(a * b)

    BigDecimal c = 20.38
    BigDecimal d = 20
    println(c * d)
```

However if you cant change the type of the Variable, then you can use decimal format to format the output to your desired format

```
    String pattern = "##,##0.00";
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    println(decimalFormat.format(c * d))
    println(decimalFormat.format(a * b))
```

Coming to why Doubles behave this way, it comes down to the way numbers are represented internally. There are a few good blogs on how float/doubles loose number precision (float precision loss ) . Long story short, due to the way its represented in memory floats/doubles loose precision, but BigDecimal representation doesnt suffer from this loss. Here are a few links that have more info.
https://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2014/may/com-2014-iss51/losing-my-precision-tips-for-handling-tricky-floating-point-arithmetic/ .
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance .

Hope this helps